# The method POST is not allowed for this resource. Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run a simple GuestBook page through GAE. It displays a textfield and a button right next to it. When the button is pressed, there seems to be error in the POST method. The code looks fine to me, I know it's only a small error I just can't seem to be able to find it.

```
import webapp2
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("""<h1>Hello, world.</h1>
        <br> <form action="/sign" method=post>
        <textarea name=content rows=2 cols=30></textarea>
        <br><input type=submit value="Sign GuestBook">
        </form>""")

class GuestBook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    self.response.write('<h2>You wrote:</h2> %s' % self.request.get('content'))

APP = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', MainHandler),
    ('/sign', GuestBook),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: In general it's a good idea to include the exact error (with the traceback) in your question, it's a very useful piece of information.

Comment: The exact error is in the title. Next time i'll include it in the question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [URI routing](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html):

> This is how it works: a list of routes is registered in the WSGI
>   application. When the application receives a request, it tries to
>   match each one in order until one matches, and then call the
>   corresponding handler.

In your case the `'/.*'` pattern for `MainHandler` also matches the `'/sign'` one for the `GuestBook` and is also placed **before** it in the `APP`'s list, so `MainHandler` is invoked instead of `GuestBook` which you'd expect. And `MainHandler` doesn't have a `post()` method, hence the error.

To fix it just swap the order of the patterns in the `APP`'s list:

```
APP = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/sign', GuestBook),
    ('/.*', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```